# Search all Fields VB6 Listview

Tags: database, listview, search, vb6

This is my search code. But it just searches in my field Product Name. I want to search all my field or my db. Here is my other fields. ProductNumber, ProductName, GenericName, PrescriptedTo, Weight, StockPiece, PricePiece, DateArrived, Expiry

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
ListView1.ListItems.Clear
ConnectDB
 rs.Open "Select * from inventory where ProductName LIKE '%" & txtSearch & "%' ORDER BY Expiry ASC", db, 3, 3
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs(0))
            For x = 1 To 8
                list.SubItems(x) = rs(x)
        Next x
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you know about `OR` operator in `WHERE` clause? `ProductName LIKE {pattern} OR ProductNumber LIKE {pattern} OR ...`

Comment: It is always better to search the database directly versus searching through the UI unless you have strict application requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use `or` to specify each column you wish to search.
2. Concatenate all the columns you wish to search. For example:

   ```
   "... where ProductName+ProductNumber+GenericName like '%" & txtSearch & "%'"
   ```

They will need to be character fields (or cast to character fields) for concatenation to work, however.